# How to make transitions when toggling elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

To preface: excuse my naivety, I am new to web development!

So on [my website](http://www.stanley-kwong.appspot.com) I have three elements in my navigation bar, all of which are toggled once clicked. It is clearly not finished right now, but I'm trying to get the design of it down first. I am trying to incorporate some sort of transition into the toggle, perhaps some sort of fade-in, but am unsure of how to proceed. Is there a way to make it so when the function is triggered (i.e. the gray box appears), the box transitions in, rather than appearing instantaneously?

The Javascript for the toggle function is as follows:

```
function toggle_visibility(x, y, z) { 

    /* Each variable stores one of the 3 elements that are on the navbar */
    var a = document.getElementById(x); 
    var b = document.getElementById(y); 
    var c = document.getElementById(z);

    if (a.style.display == 'none') { 
        a.style.display = 'block'; 
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        a.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I am also having an issue where it takes two clicks to toggle the display initially, but I'll try to fix that later.

Comment: You can do everything like this with just `CSS`, if you want to use some script, I think you should try using `jQuery` (a very popular javascript library for web development) which supports you many things including transitioning...

Comment: Don’t try to implement stuff like this yourself, especially as a beginner – but rather use a framework like f.e. jQuery and the methods it provides for situations like this (fadeIn, fadeOut).

Comment: now days [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)is a really powerfull tool, with jquey you can simply do this to add effects: `$( "#mydiv" ).fadeIn();`

Comment: And with the jQuery comments... don't use the `onclick` html attribute.  You should keep your javascript [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery to create an animation. You can do this by adding a class to an element to change its state and then add the animation via CSS.
Here is [a tutorial](http://www.vikaskbh.com/native-jquery-animations-using-pure-javascript-css3/) on how to do exactly what you are looking for.
If you don't want to create the animation by yourself you can use something like [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using jquery. It makes transitions and animations so much easier.

something like:

```
$("#ToggleID/.Class").hover(function(){
      $("#ToggleID/.Class").show(`duration of the animation`);
});
```

Jquery : http://jquery.com/

Jquery Animations : https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: This isn't much of an answer, considering: the OP doesn't specify that he wants to use jQuery, you've shown no examples, this is basically just a restatement of the above comments.